# Problem with uvicorn when I ran FastAPI code

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn

I have this error when I run uvicorn for each FastAPI codes :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h11._receivebuffer'
```

But I installed h11 with pip.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing:

```
import h11
```

https://h11.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably in the way you run `uvicorn`. I had the same issue when trying

```
uvicorn main:app
```

but the correct way to run uvicorn often is

```
python -m uvicorn main:app
```

which, at least for me, worked.